# Converting babel compiled code into regular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, babeljs

I got an example code from codepen and I wanted to understand it better. I noticed that the js code is compiled with Babel. Since I'm quite new to JS I would be more comfortable to look at a standard javascript code, so I wanted to ask you if there's some way to convert a babel js into a regular js. I did some research but I couldn't find anything

By the way, this is the Babel code

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("projects");
const closeButton = document.getElementById("project-close");
const projectItems = document.querySelectorAll(".project-item");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", onProjectClose);
projectItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", onProjectClick));

function onProjectClick(event) {
  const { target } = event;
  const { width, height, top, left } = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const clone = document.createElement("div");
  clone.style.height = height + "px";
  clone.style.width = width + "px";
  clone.style.top = top + "px";
  clone.style.left = left + "px";
  clone.style.position = "absolute";
  clone.style.zIndex = 10;
  clone.classList.add("project-item");
  clone.classList.add("clone");
  clone.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(clone);

  gsap.timeline().
  to(clone, 1.5, {
    position: "fixed",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    ease: Expo.easeInOut }).

  add(() => document.body.classList.add("project-page")).
  set(clone, {
    overflow: "auto" });

}

function onProjectClose() {
  document.body.classList.remove("project-page");
  const clone = document.querySelector(".clone");
  gsap.to(clone, 1, {
    clipPath: "inset(100% 0 100% 0)",
    ease: Sine.easeInOut,
    onComplete() {
      clone.remove();
    } });

  gsap.to(clone.querySelector("img"), 1, {
    scale: 0.7,
    ease: Sine.easeInOut });

}
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript code snippet. What do you mean by babel code?